# Marking a method as always-called in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm extending `Phaser.Scene`, and I have some members that aren't defined in `create`:

```js
class Foo extends Phaser.Scene {
    inventory: Phaser.GameObjects.Text[]

    constructor(key) {
        super(key)
    }

    create() {
        inventory = [this.add.text(...)]
    }
}
```

Typescript doesn't like that I'm not initializing `inventory` in `constructor` (TS2564), and I've had to `// @ts-ignore` it. Is there any way I can fool Typescript into believing that `create` is always called in the constructor, and take the burden of other usages into my own hands?

Comment: The non-null assertion works. Thank you! This did not come up in my searching because `create` is not called by me.

Comment: TypeScript is helping you by preventing a mistake here — because you're not actually invoking the method in the constructor, so the `inventory` property really should be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties): `inventory?: Phaser.GameObjects.Text[]` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/NVYo5w))

Comment: I specified in my question that I would like to "take the burden of other usages into my own hands": I do not want to mark it as optional, as, unless I made a bigger mistake, there will not be a case where it will be undefined on usage.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76159660/marking-a-method-as-always-called-in-typescript#comment134309675_76159660) @Aly Initializing with an empty array is safer if discriminating `undefined` at usage sites is undesirable: `inventory: Phaser.GameObjects.Text[] = []` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/w22D8w))